# python scatterplot - add legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have written the following function to use scatterplot to plot the data

```py
def draw(tmp, labels, lvalues):
    """tmp: feature values
    labels: transformed label values after encode
    lvalues: actually lable values
    """
    X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(tmp)
    color = ['#ff0000', '#ffff00', '#00ff00', '#00ffff', '#0000ff', '#ff00ff', '#990000', '#999900', '#009900',
             '#009999']

    x_list = [x for [x, y] in X_embedded]
    y_list = [y for [x, y] in X_embedded]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

    plt.scatter(x_list, y_list, marker='x', c=labels, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(color))
    # plt.savefig('cl_1.0.png')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

**Issues:** the code is working as intended, however, I am not able to add legend into the figure.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot get a colorbar (which appears next to the plot and shows the color-value relation) or an actual legend entry that shows a colormap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I prefer to work with plotly which you can customize more, is interactive and nicer.

Making some dummy data

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"x": np.random.random(100),
                        "y": np.random.random(100),
                        "z": random.choices(["A", "B"], k=100)})
```

[image]

Plotting the scatterplot. Notice that in every `add_trace(go.Scatter())` there is a name argument where you specify the name of the trace. This is the name that will automatically be shown in the legend.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    y=df[df['z'] == 'A']['x'],
    x=df[df['z'] == 'A']['y'],
    mode='markers',
    name='1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    y=df[df['z'] == 'B']['x'],
    x=df[df['z'] == 'B']['y'],
    mode='markers',
    name='2'
))
fig.update_layout(
    title=dict(text='Plot title'),
    xaxis_title="X-asis title",
    yaxis_title="Y-axis title")
```

[image]

Edit:
This can be done more easily with plotly express

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(df,
                x="x",
                y="y",
                color="z",
                title="Plot title")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your labels in order for your legend to appear. Try this:

```
def draw(tmp, labels, lvalues):
    """tmp: feature values
    labels: transformed label values after encode
    lvalues: actual label values
    """
    X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(tmp)
    color = ['#ff0000', '#ffff00', '#00ff00', '#00ffff', '#0000ff', '#ff00ff', '#990000', '#999900', '#009900',
             '#009999']

    x_list = [x for [x, y] in X_embedded]
    y_list = [y for [x, y] in X_embedded]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.scatter(x_list, y_list, marker='x', c=labels, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(color))
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the colormap legend?
if you mean this, you can just add: `plt.colorbar()`

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

plt.scatter(x_list, y_list, marker='x', c=labels, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(color))
# plt.savefig('cl_1.0.png')
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```